# Is "teeming brain" a metaphor?

Tags: metaphors

I am working about the figuritive language in Keats sonnet "when I have fears". Is "teeming brain" in line two a metaphor?

I'm struggling to understand because English is my second language.

Here is the sonnet:

> When I have fears that I may cease to be
>   Before my pen has glean'd my **teeming brain**,
>   Before high pil`d books, in charact'ry,
>   Hold like rich garners the full-ripen'd grain;
>   When I behold, upon the night's starr'd face,
>   Huge cloudy symbols of a high romance,
>   And feel that I may never live to trace
>   Their shadows, with the magic hand of chance;
>   And when I feel, fair creature of an hour!
>   That I shall never look upon thee more, Never have relish in the faery power
>   Of unreflecting love;—then on the shore
>   Of the wide world I stand alone, and think,
>   Till Love and Fame to nothingness do sink.

Comment: If you want people to answer, it would be helpful if you were to quote the relevant passage from Keats.  Not many people are going to bother to look it up just to answer a short question.

Comment: A 1-minute internet search found this analysis of the poem:  http://academic.brooklyn.cuny.edu/english/melani/cs6/fear.html, which may answer your question.  Please review that article and come back with a more specific question if that doesn't answer it for you.  Please do some research yourself and explain what you have done & what you still don't understand before posting questions like this on this forum.

Comment: What does "glean" mean (look it up).  Then answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the sense that the brain as a bodily organ can "teem" with neural activity, electrical energy, chemicals, etc, then no: "teeming brain" is not a metaphor but rather a literal description.

If instead we read this expression as referring to the metaphysical "mind" teeming with thoughts, ideas, emotions and, more specifically, unwritten poetry, then "brain" might perhaps be thought of as a metaphor for "mind" - but to make such a fine distinction between "brain" and "mind" is probably unwarranted in this case, the two terms can be regarded as roughly synonymous and there is therefore no metaphorical usage.

However, the broader expression "my pen has glean'd my teeming brain" is *definitely* a metaphor, as we're not meant to read it literally, i.e. that a pen is inserted into the brain to collect the poetry inside. If only writing poetry were that easy!